# Loop stuck to last entry python

Tags: python, json, loops

I'm reading a file and I want to append data in an array then dumps it in json file. i'm using python 2.7.

The problem is that it only returns the last line of the file and populate the file with this.
Don't know if it's clear so I show the code

```
import re
import json

results = []
contact = {
    "id":"",
    "email":""
}


source = open('zen_id.txt')
output = open('zen_id_js.json', 'w')
for line in source:
    email = re.search(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', line)
    contact['email'] = email.group(0)
    p = re.search(r'\d\d\d\d\d', line)
    contact['id'] = p.group(0)
    results.append(contact)

json.dump(results, output)
```

And the output is :

```
[
  {
    "id": "35148",
    "email": "****@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "35148",
    "email": "****@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "35148",
    "email": "****@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "35148",
    "email": "****@gmail.com"
  },
```

Anyone knows what s happening ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: define `contact = {
    "id":"",
    "email":""
}
` _inside_ the loop. Else the reference is reused. A classic

Comment: Make it an answer @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: Thanks a lot! Silly me...

Comment: I've tried to find a duplicate, but I couldn't (I'm sure there are a lot of ones but hard to put my hands on it...)

Comment: btw we can replace noisy `\d\d\d\d\d` with `\d{5}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by doing

```
contact = {
    "id":"",
    "email":""
}
```

*outside* the loop, you have one instance of the object. You just modify the same instance over and over again (`result.append` doesn't create a copy of the dictionary, only stores the reference)

One solution is to define it *inside* the loop or to create a *copy*

```
for line in source:
    email = re.search(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', line)
    contact = {}  # create a new, empty instance
    contact['email'] = email.group(0)
    ...
```

note that it is not necessary to define the dictionary with keys & empty values, since you're overwriting them anyway. Define it empty.

Another alternative is not to use `contact` at all and create the dictionary on-the-fly using a literal form when appending to the list:

```
results.append({"email":email.group(0), "id":p.group(0)})
```

you can also skip the loop altogether and write that in one line using list comprehension:

```
results = [{"email":re.search(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', line).group(0), "id":re.search(r'\d\d\d\d\d', line).group(0)} for line in source]
```

The only issue here is that you cannot handle the cases where there isn't a match, at least easily.

Comment: Thanks so much for you detailed answer !

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the contact dictionary inside the for loop.

```
import re
import json

results = []



source = open('zen_id.txt')
output = open('zen_id_js.json', 'w')
for line in source:
    contact = {
        "id": "",
        "email": ""
    }
    email = re.search(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', line)
    contact['email'] = email.group(0)
    p = re.search(r'\d\d\d\d\d', line)
    contact['id'] = p.group(0)
    results.append(contact)

json.dump(results, output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform deepcopy.

```
  import re
  import json
  import copy

  results = []
  contact = {
      "id":"",
      "email":""
  }


  source = open('zen_id.txt')
  output = open('zen_id_js.json', 'w')
  for line in source:
      email = re.search(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', line)
      contact['email'] = email.group(0)
      p = re.search(r'\d\d\d\d\d', line)
      contact['id'] = p.group(0)
      results.append(copy.deepcopy(contact))

  json.dump(results, output)
```